# Why does Tensorflow LearningRateScheduler *increase* (not decrease) the learning rate with each epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

On the Coursera class "TensorFlow in Practice -- Sequeneces, Time Series and Prediction" the 9th video of the second week uses a callback to dynamically increase (not decrease) the learning rate. I understand why we need to dynamically adjust the rate; but this callback is *increasing* the learning rate with each epoch. Don't we want to do the opposite and gradually *decrease* the learning rate as the neural net learns more? I'm sure the video is correct (it was created by Andrew Ng and Google, who obviously know a lot about TensorFlow) but why are we increasing (instead of decreasing) the learning rate? Is keras actually using the inverse of this number as the learning rate, or something like that?

```
#Doesn't the next line *increase* the learning rate with each callback?
#But shouldn't we be gradually decreasing it? 
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(
    lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10**(epoch / 20))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-8, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=100, callbacks=[lr_schedule], verbose=0)
```

And here's a full code example from the sample notebook that they provide with this example:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%204%20-%20S%2BP/S%2BP%20Week%202%20Lesson%203.ipynb

Is it correct to increase the learning rate with each epoch? Won't that result in the optimizer "over-shooting" the answer on each epoch and never converging to a solution?

Comment: It is called warm up.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933867/what-does-learning-rate-warm-up-mean
(how do I refer to this properly?)

Comment: But the learning rate will increase and increase forever. Won't that prevent the neural net from converging to a solution? Won't the optimizer keep "over-shooting" the target on each step?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It does not make any sense to actually do this when the goal is to train a network. Might they be doing this to demonstrate that your learning rate can be too high? the graph just after it might be showing such a lesson.

Comment: Also note that they are not reusing the callback function LearningRateScheduler in the following model fits