# How should I understand warmup learning rate in tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

Could you explain how it works during training?

````
learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 8e-2
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: .0001
          warmup_steps: 400
        }
      }```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

answering my own question :) With the setting above, training starts with lr=0.0001 and reaches to 0.08 at the end of 400 epochs (warmup_steps). Until 400th epoch lr is incremented linearly.

Comment: Could you post your full code example of using learning rate warmup?

Comment: I have used tensorflow object detectıon api. You can check from this link https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. You can see warm-up LR in config files of models.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to increase the learning rate over time? If I'm not wrong, it is better to first have a learning rate and then as we reach the optimum, it should be lesser and lesser as we do not want to cross the optimum.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942518/11758585 link can help to you.